# How to set thousand separator for PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, formatting, locale

I want to format long numbers using thousand separator. It can be done using `to_char` function just like:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(76543210.98, '999G999G990D00')
```

But when my PostgreSQL server with UTF-8 encoding is on Polish version of Windows such SELECT ends with:

```
ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xa0
HINT:  This error can also happen if the byte sequence does not match the encoding expected by the server, which is controlled by "client_encoding".
```

In `to_char` pattern `G` is described as: *group separator (uses locale)*.
This SELECT works without error when server is running on Linux with Polish locale.

As a workaround I use space instead of `G` in format string, but I think there should be way to set thousand separator just like in Oracle:

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS=', ';
```

Is such setting available for PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 21):

If you use `psql`, you can execute this:

```
\pset numericlocale
```

Example:

```
test=# create temporary table a (a numeric(20,10));
CREATE TABLE

test=# insert into a select random() * 1000000 from generate_series(1,3);
INSERT 0 3

test=# select * from a;
         a         
-------------------
 287421.6944910590
 140297.9311533270
 887215.3805568810
(3 rows)

test=# \pset numericlocale
Showing locale-adjusted numeric output.

test=# select * from a;
         a          
--------------------
 287.421,6944910590
 140.297,9311533270
 887.215,3805568810    
(3 rows)
```

Comment: To do this permanently, put `\pset numericlocale` in `~/.psqlrc`.

Comment: To switch it off, use: `\pset numericlocale off`.

Answer (score 4):

I'm pretty sure the error message is literally true: 0xa0 isn't a valid UTF-8 character.

My home server is running PostgreSQL on Windows XP, SP3. I can do this in psql.

```
sandbox=# show client_encoding;
 client_encoding
-----------------
 UTF8
(1 row)


sandbox=# show lc_numeric;
  lc_numeric
---------------
 polish_poland
(1 row)


sandbox=# SELECT TO_CHAR(76543210.98, '999G999G990D00');
     to_char
-----------------
   76┬á543┬á210,98
(1 row)
```

I don't get an error message, but I get garbage for the separator. Could this be a code page issue?

> As a workaround I use space instead of
>   G in format string

Let's think about this. If you use a space, then on a web page the value might split at the end of a line or at the boundary of a table cell. I'd think a nonbreaking space might be a better choice.

And, in Unicode, a nonbreaking space is 0xa0. In Unicode, not in UTF8. (That is, 0xa0 can't be the first byte of a UTF8 character. See [UTF-8 Bit Distribution](http://www.unicode.org/versions/corrigendum1.html).)

Another possibility is that your client is expecting one byte order, and the server is giving it a different byte order. Since the numbers are single-byte characters, the byte order wouldn't matter until, well, it mattered. If the client is expecting a big endian MB character, and it got a little endian MB character beginning with 0xa0, I'd expect it to die with the error message you saw. I'm not sure I have a way to test this before I go to work today.

Comment: You are right, you probably tested it with PostgreSQL 9.0.2, I tested it with 9.0.1 and it works, but shows "garbage" on console. With JDBC or ODBC client it works without garbage so I think it was bug in PostgreSQL which was repaired. But question: "Can I set temporary thousand separator?" stays unanswered. Probably not in actual versions of PostgreSQL.

Comment: @Michal Niklas: See my edit above. I'm not sure of its significance.

Comment: Thanks. My client works ok for some time (psql shows garbage on console because console uses CP852). Problems with select was solved with new version of PostgreSQL. But even with 9.0.2 I do not know how to set thousand separator to dot when I want to import CSV file with dots, and then set thousand separator to comma when some other customer send me file with commas. Now I have to convert such file with Python/Perl etc. With Oracle I can set some session vars and database converts it.

Comment: If you can run PostgreSQL on your desktop you can probably work around that problem. You can change the localization settings in postgresql.conf and restart the server. Import data to your desktop first, then push it on to the company's server. (I've been told that LC_NUMERIC gives Oracle a lot of trouble, too.)